# NoReverseMatch while trying to match dates with regular expression in url

Tags: django

In my URL I expect to get 2 dates as input:

```
url(r'^export/range/csv/(?P<start_date>\d+)/(?P<end_date>\d+)/$', views.export_payment_range_csv, name="export_payment_range_csv"),
```

But I am getting error :

> NoReverseMatch at /payment/list/range/ Reverse for
>   'export_payment_range_csv' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{u'start_date': datetime.date(2016, 2, 1), u'end_date':
>   datetime.date(2016, 12, 31)}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['condition/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$',
>   'payment/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$']

I assume this has to do with regular expression in my URL file.
what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
URL I access

```
<li><a href="{% url 'export_payment_range_csv' start_date=start_date  end_date=end_date %}">CSV for current range payments</a>
```

When start date and end date I got during template  rendering from the view.

I expect dates on the view side

```
 payment_list = LeasePaymentFilter(request.GET, queryset=LeasePayment.objects.filter(payment_date__range=[start_date, end_date]))
```

Comment: And what is the url that you are trying to access?

Comment: I wrote update in question.

Answer (score 3):

Your url parameters expects digits (`\d+`),  for example:

```
reverse("export_payment_range_csv", kwargs={
    'start_date': '123', 
    'end_date': '456',
})
```

but you pass `datetime.date` instances:

```
reverse("export_payment_range_csv", kwargs={
    'start_date': d1, 
    'end_date': d2,
})
```

check the view itself (the function `views.export_payment_range_csv()`) and see what format is expected for the parameters, and generate the needed string, for example:

```
def format_my_date(d):
     return d.strftime("%Y%m%d")

reverse("export_payment_range_csv", kwargs={
    'start_date': format_my_date(d1), 
    'end_date': format_my_date(d2),
})
```

Comment: Thanks. View Expects dates , since I use date range on the view side 
 payment_list = LeasePaymentFilter(request.GET, queryset=LeasePayment.objects.filter(payment_date__range=[start_date, end_date]))